# Multiple XSL files combination

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

[image]Hi I  have two xsl files and I have one xml how can I combine these xsl files together at transform type and combine them it and get one html

index.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [<!ENTITY nbsp "&#xa0;"><!ENTITY bull "&#x2022;">]>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:include href="hello.xsl"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="name" /></td>
    </tr>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and then my send xsl is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
 <!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [<!ENTITY nbsp "&#xa0;"><!ENTITY bull "&#x2022;">]>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:template match="/">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="age" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and my xml is

```
 <xml>
    <name>abc</name>
    <age>15</age>
</xml>
```

What I want output is like

```
<html>
    <tr><td>abc</td></tr>
     <table>
        <tr><td>15</td></tr>
     </table>
 </html>
```

Is that is do able thing to perform in xsl I search so many site but couldn't find answer, plz help

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: You edited your question and are now asking something completely different.

As I said, you can combine templates and other element from separate stylesheets with `xsl:include` and `xsl:import`. See the relevant section of the specification [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Combining-Stylesheets).

---

There are ways to combine separate stylesheets (e.g. via `xsl:include` and `xsl:import`), but in your case I do not think it is even necessary.

Your stylesheets only have one template each and they simply retrieve values from an input XML which is a trivial action. There is really no need to store those two templates in separate stylesheets.

Write *one* stylesheet that produces both the `html` element and the table.

Let me emphasize another thing: It is evident in your question that you do not really understand the workings of both XSLT and HTML. To give a few hints:

- the output you request is malformed HTML. A `tr` element cannot be an immediate child of `html`. Content must be placed inside `body`, as opposed to `header`.
- both of the templates you show match `/`. Obviously, it makes no sense to combine them if they match the same node.

Please take the time to study the basics of XSLT and HTML before asking a new question.

**Stylesheet**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/xml">
        <html>
          <body>
            <table border="solid">
                <tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="*">
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
                        </td>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="*[1]"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="*[2]"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
          </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<html>
  <body>
   <table border="solid">
      <tr>
         <td>name</td>
         <td>age</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>abc</td>
         <td>15</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just put a sample this is not my actual requirement I have 50 xsls so I want to know the basics of doing it if so I can apply that logic to make user my thing actual program works.

Comment: @RezgHansa Are you using GoogleTranslate, by any chance? It is very unclear what you are asking, I'm afraid. You really need to explain your _actual_ requirement of course.

Comment: What my actual requirement is, I have 50 different types of components in xsl files (imagine some thing like widgets) and I have 10 main types of xsls and those 10 main xsls need to add those individual components/widgets in to those, most of them are over and over using so I dont want code them over and over again in those 10 xsls instead of that I want them use as plug able manner

Comment: I attached my problem in image format as well (above comment) for more clear idea. ( in pink color which I mentioned is my components that 50 sub xsls and blue color ones are my main types 10 xsls) so final out come is those blue color ones and those are made using that pink color components